# Full recovery model and tablock inserts logging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2017

When testing some queries, I set the recovery model to full on a database and ran two identical 1M row inserts, with and without `TABLOCK`.

On the one with `TABLOCK`, I got around `9295` log records on a sql server 2008 instance, and around `8714` log records on a SQL Server 2017 instance.

When running the insert without tablock, I get around `1035659` records for the 2008 instance and around `1068599` records for the 2017 instance.

The reason for testing on sql server 2008 is to match the [data loading performance guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)'s statement on the recovery models for ML operations :

> Minimally logged operations are available only if your database is in
>   bulk-logged or simple recovery mode.

So, what am Is seeing here if it is not minimal logging?

```
Use DatabaseName

ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseName TO DISK = '\\location\DatabaseName.bak';

BACKUP LOG DatabaseName TO DISK = '\\location\DatabaseName_log.trn';
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Accounts', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.Accounts;
END;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Accounts( AccountID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                            AccountName varchar(255),
                            DateCreated DATETIME2);

-- Insert 1M Rows into dbo.Account without TABLOCK
GO
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.Accounts  (AccountID,AccountName,DateCreated)
SELECT TOP(1000000)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        'Name N ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS varchar(255)),
        DATEADD(MINUTE,-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),GETDATE())
FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES SPT1
CROSS APPLY MASTER..SPT_VALUES SPT2;
GO
-- check the amount of records in the log file
SELECT count(*)
FROM
fn_dbLog(NULL,NULL);
--1035659 rows
GO

-- clear the log
BACKUP LOG DatabaseName to disk = '\\location\DatabaseName_log2.trn';

GO

--drop the table

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Accounts', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.Accounts;
END;
GO
-- create the table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Accounts( AccountID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                            AccountName varchar(255),
                            DateCreated DATETIME2);

-- Insert 1M Rows into dbo.Account WITH TABLOCK
GO
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.Accounts WITH(TABLOCK) (AccountID,AccountName,DateCreated)
SELECT TOP(1000000)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        'Name N ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS varchar(255)),
        DATEADD(MINUTE,-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),GETDATE())
FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES SPT1
CROSS APPLY MASTER..SPT_VALUES SPT2;
GO
-- check the amount of records in the log file
SELECT count(*)
FROM
fn_dbLog(NULL,NULL);

--9295 rows
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `TABLOCK` your `logging` even in `full model` is called "efficient logging", it's when instead of logging every `insert` row-by-row the whole `pages` are logged.

It would be `minimally logged` in `simple` and `bulk logged` modes with only `page allocations` in the `log`, but in `full` recovery model you have fully formatted `pages` of `data`.

So the number of `records` that go to the log in `simple` and `full` models when inserting with `tablock` will be nearly the same but the content is different: in `simple`/`bulk logged` there will be only page numbers, in full there will be complete `pages`.

And it is really `full logging` since the `insert` **operation can be fully reconstituted** using these log records while in `simple`/`bulk logged` you have only information sufficient to `rollback` the `insert`.